# Uso de la variable local no asignada "Cuadrado"

Tags: c#

Soy novato en este lenguaje y he buscado el problema pero no termino de entender, me dice "Uso de la variable local no asignada "Cuadrado" ", se supone que el código es para hacer la suma de los cuadrados de N números

```
    {
        double x, num, cuadrado;
        x = 1;
        
        
        num = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        for (x=1;x==num;)
        {
            cuadrado = cuadrado + Math.Pow(x, 2);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(cuadrado);
```

Comment: Eso es pq no estás inicializando la variable, pon cuadrado = 0; como tal esto no es un error si no una advertencia del compilador

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hallar la suma de los cuadrados sería:

```
int suma = 0;
int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

for(int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
{
   suma = suma + (i * i);
}

Console.WriteLine(suma);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Se hace un **ciclo for** desde **1** hasta el número introducido y se va hallando el cuadrado por cada número del ciclo y sumándolo al valor de la **variable suma**, posteriormente se imprime el resultado.

Otra forma de hacerlo sería usando **Linq**:

```
var suma = Enumerable.Range(1, num).Sum(n => n * n);
```

Genero una lista desde **1** hasta **num** y sumo cada cuadrado de la lista generada, todo esto con una sola línea de código, para usar **Linq** debes añadir en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

De esta forma te ahorras varias líneas de código .